# No route matches [GET] "/links/www.twitter.com.au"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello building a reddit clone.

When i click on this link found here http://postimg.org/delete/saq41zozs/ it should go another website. In this case it's www.twitter.com.au

Error  found here http://postimg.org/delete/uhlsxso1e/

Im guessing because i don't have a twitter.com route. I don't know how to set it up so it routes to twitter.com

Here's my routes.rb.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments

  devise_for :users

  resources :links do
    member do
      put "like",    to: "links#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    end

  resources :comments
  end

  root "links#index"
```

Here is my show.html.erb

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><a href="<%= @link.url %>"><%= @link.title %></a><br> <small>Submitted by <%= @link.user.name %></small></h1>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <%= link_to 'Visit URL', @link.url, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>

<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <%= link_to like_link_path(@link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    Upvote
    <%= @link.get_upvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to dislike_link_path(@link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
    Downvote
    <%= @link.get_downvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<% if @link.user == current_user -%>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(@link), class: "btn btn-default" %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', @link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<h3 class="comments_title">
  <%= @link.comments.count %> Comments
</h3>

<div id="comments">
  <%= render :partial => @link.comments %>
</div>
<%= simple_form_for [@link, Comment.new]  do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are linking to an external site, as opposed to a relative url, you need to prepend your link with 'http'. Just change the link in question to:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%= link_to @link.title, "http://#{@link.url}" %><br> <small>Submitted by <%= @link.user.name %></small></h1>
</div>
```